# Ranking Number Array Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got an array of numbers and I'd like to display them in descending order but as a rank (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc) instead of their number values while taking ties (equal number values) into consideration.

I've got the sorting as follows:

```
function mySorting(a, b) {
        a = a;
        b = b;
        return a == b ? 0 : (b < a ? -1 : 1)
    }
```

Which works fine with the call:

```
var myArray=[28,92,12,12,2];
myArray.sort(mySorting);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I would then rank the values of myArray with 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. taking ties into account?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: sort the array ascending as usual, then build a new array that uses the keys as your ranking, and has subarrays to list the original values, or at least how many of the original values are in that slot, e.g. for your sample data `[0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:1]` for 92,28,12,12,2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can take advantage of 2 array methods `$.inArray()` and `$.grep`

Create an array of the unique values to use for rank:

```
var ranks = $.grep(myArray, function(item, idx) {
    return item != myArray[idx - 1];
}).reverse();/* your sort function is descending I added reverse to the ranks , remove if needed*/
```

Useage:

```
$.each(myArray, function(idx, item) {
    var rank= $.inArray( item, ranks)+1;/* index position and add one for 1st,second etc*/
    $('body').append('Rank of '+item+ ' is '+ rank+'<br>')

})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/XWs5j/1/

API References:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

**EDIT:** Additional demo to create array of "ties" and modify output for values that tie

http://jsfiddle.net/XWs5j/2/

Comment: Thank you for the push in the right direction. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks again for the help w/ my first query. I'm wondering now how i would modify this to use it with a nested array. For example: var myArray=[["a",28],["b",92],["c",12],["d",12],["e",2]]. How would I use the same code to eval based on position [1] in each element of the nested array? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: `return item[1] != myArray[idx - 1][1];` - assumes that you have sorted array based on the number values

Comment: i tried that and get the following error myArray[...].1' is null or not an object. what am i doing wrong?